# Properties and QGraphicsSimpleTextItem

Tags: qt, properties, qgraphicssimpletextitem

I was wondering if we could use properties to animate in a class which inherits *QGraphicsSimpleTextItem*?

I'm drawing this button :

[image]

It is made up of :

- A circle, which inherits QGraphicsObject and override the geometry property
- An ellipse, which basicaly is the same but takes the circle as a parent
- A text, which inherits **QObject** and **QGraphicsSimpleTextItem**

For the first two, the animations works. But concerning the last one, I have the followings errors :

```
QPropertyAnimation: you're trying to animate a non-existing property localisation of your QObject
QPropertyAnimation: you're trying to animate a non-existing property localisation of your QObject
QPropertyAnimation: you're trying to animate a non-existing property sizePolicy of your QObject
QPropertyAnimation: you're trying to animate a non-existing property sizePolicy of your QObject
```

Here is my class 'MyText' :

```
class MyTextOk : public QObject, public QGraphicsSimpleTextItem
{
    Q_PROPERTY(QPointF localisation READ localisation WRITE setLocalisation)
    Q_PROPERTY(QFont sizePolicy READ sizePolicy WRITE setSizePolicy)
public:
    explicit MyTextOk(QGraphicsObject *parent = 0);
    ~MyTextOk();

    QPointF localisation() const;
    void setLocalisation(const QPointF &value);

    QFont sizePolicy() const;
    void setSizePolicy(const QFont &value);

private:
    QRectF boundingRect() const;

protected :
    QPointF point;
    QFont font;
};
```

And my .ccp

```
QVariant myFontInterpolator(const QFont &start, const QFont &end, qreal progress)
{
    if (progress<0.5)
    {
        int a = (1-progress)*50 + progress*45;
        QFont rt(start);
        rt.setPointSize(a);
        return rt;
    }
    else
    {
        int a = (1-progress)*45 + progress*50;
        QFont rt(start);
        rt.setPointSize(a);
        return rt;
    }
        Q_UNUSED(end)
}

MyTextOk::MyTextOk(QGraphicsObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent), QGraphicsSimpleTextItem(parent)
{
    point = QPointF(-40,-45);
    this->setText("Ok");
    this->setPos(point);
    this->setBrush(QBrush(Qt::white));
    font = QFont("Colibri",50);
    this->setFont(font);

    qRegisterAnimationInterpolator<QFont>(myFontInterpolator);
}

MyTextOk::~MyTextOk()
{

}

QPointF MyTextOk::localisation() const
{
    return point;
}

void MyTextOk::setLocalisation(const QPointF &value)
{
    if(point!=value)
    {
        point = value;
        update();
    }
}

QFont MyTextOk::sizePolicy() const
{
    return font;
}

void MyTextOk::setSizePolicy(const QFont &value)
{
    if(font!=value)
    {
        font=value;
        update();
    }
}

QRectF MyTextOk::boundingRect() const
{
    return QRectF(0,0,0,0);
}
```

And in my MainWindow I animate :

```
void MainWindow::lancerAnimBoutonRond()
{
    animationBoutonRondTaille = new QPropertyAnimation(roundButton, "geometry");

    animationBoutonRondTaille->setDuration(300);
    animationBoutonRondTaille->setKeyValueAt(0, QRectF(-90, -90, 180, 180));
    animationBoutonRondTaille->setKeyValueAt(0.5, QRectF(-85,-85,170,170));
    animationBoutonRondTaille->setKeyValueAt(1, QRectF(-90, -90, 180, 180));

    animationBoutonRondTaille -> start();

    animationBoutonRondEllipse = new QPropertyAnimation(whiteShadow, "geometry");

    animationBoutonRondEllipse->setDuration(300);
    animationBoutonRondEllipse->setKeyValueAt(0,QRectF(-70,-80,140,80));
    animationBoutonRondEllipse->setKeyValueAt(0.5,QRectF(-65,-75,130,90));
    animationBoutonRondEllipse->setKeyValueAt(1,QRectF(-70,-80,140,80));

    animationBoutonRondEllipse->start(); // These two work

    animationBoutonRondOk = new QPropertyAnimation(textOk,"localisation");

    animationBoutonRondOk->setDuration(300);
    animationBoutonRondOk->setKeyValueAt(0,QPointF(-40,-45));
    animationBoutonRondOk->setKeyValueAt(0.5,QPointF(-35, -40));
    animationBoutonRondOk->setKeyValueAt(1,QPointF(-40, -45));

    animationBoutonRondOk->start(); //error : QPropertyAnimation: you're trying to animate a non-existing property localisation of your QObject

    animationBoutonRondOkTaille = new QPropertyAnimation(textOk,"sizePolicy");

    animationBoutonRondOkTaille->setDuration(300);
    animationBoutonRondOkTaille->setStartValue(QFont("Colibri",50));
    animationBoutonRondOkTaille->setEndValue(QFont("Colibri",50));

    animationBoutonRondOkTaille->start();  //error : 'QPropertyAnimation: you're trying to animate a non-existing property sizePolicy of your QObject'

}
```

I don't know if I can name my "own" properties, but I can't (?) override the `font` and `pos` properties since I inherits **QGraphicsSimpleTextItem** and use `setFont()` and `setPos()`

You can find all the code [here](https://github.com/TaiZzZ/roundButton) if you want to try.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I think you're just missing the `Q_OBJECT` macro in the `MyTextOk` class definition.  Although I'm surprised there weren't any warnings from `moc`.

Comment: Oh, I hate my life. In deed ! I have no more errors, but the animations remain useless. I'll come back if I have some news

Comment: Thank you it made it work. We just have to call the pos and font properties to make it work. This Q_OBJECT oversight made me think the wrong way.

Comment: Please post a solution as an answer (ensuring relevant content from a link is brought into the answer) not as an update to your question. This is to help future visitors and to reduce confusion. Thank you.

Comment: Done, thank you for your advice. It's clearer than an EDIT you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

`Q_OBJECT` macro in the `MyTextOk` class definition was missing. After placing it, the code runs fine.

You can find a working example of my button [here](https://github.com/TaiZzZ/arrowAnimation).